# Android trying to format GPS locations

Tags: android, string-formatting

I'm trying to keep a list of all the GPS locations read in.  I would like them to be formatted with:
`long:(5 digits) and lat:(5 digits).`  I have the following code:

```
placeholder = "Long: %10s  Lat: %10s";
formatted = placeholder.format( longitude,  latitude);
mDataFeed=formatted+"\n"+mDataFeed;
```

The output is long: `877678888`, there is no latitude and the string is longer then 10 charters.

This is the complete code block

```
@Override  
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {  
    String longitude = "Long: " +loc.getLongitude(); 
    viewLog.setText(longitude);  
    String latitude = "Lat: " +loc.getLatitude(); 
    viewLat.setText( latitude); 
    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

    String send=new String();
    send=longitude+" "+latitude+"\n";
    //   mDataFeed=send+mDataFeed;

    String placeholder = new String();
    String  formatted  = new String();

    placeholder = "Long: %10s  Lat: %10s";
    formatted = placeholder.format( longitude,  latitude);
    mDataFeed=formatted+"\n"+mDataFeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
formatted = placeholder.format( longitude,  latitude);
```

with

```
formatted = placeholder.format( loc.getLongitude().toString(),  loc.getLatitude().toString());
```

or alternately

```
placeholder = "Long: %10d  Lat: %10d";
formatted = placeholder.format( loc.getLongitude(),  loc.getLatitude());
```